# Nodejs change time at date type after getting from Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I wanted to change time at date type which returning from mongodb with custom time like below

```
"2021-05-26T00:00:00.000Z"
```

to

```
"2021-05-26T10:20:00.000Z"
```

I wanted to change time from a variable at the date, so my technique was split this date with "T" then get time part and change it with custom time

```
let splitedTime = timev[0].validFrom.toString().split()[0];
let customTime = "10:20:00.000Z";
let finalTime = splitedTime + customTime;
```

but this split not working this giving me date like this "Wed May 26 2021 06:00:00 GM". Can you please help me for this?

Comment: What is the point in this? Are you always adding 10 hours and 20 minutes or what? If so, you don't need to treat it as a string, treat it as a date. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date - You can also return the timestring in the above format by returning the ISO formatted string https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: @Isolated the hour:minute should vary with a variable, so this not will be always 10 hours 20minutes

Comment: and what is the expected output? I'm about to post an answer but I want to ensure it's relevant to you. If I give you "2021-05-26T00:00:00.000Z", what do you want back? Essentially, how do you plan on calculating the hour and minute variables?

Comment: also, when you use `validFrom.toString()` you don't return the ISO string (format of above), if you were to use `toISOString()` your approach would likely work. @mdkamrul

Comment: @Isolated I have edited my question. please check

Comment: how did you derive your 'customTime'? It's a user input? Let us know so we can give you a better recommendation how you can add time to a Date object.

Comment: @mdkamrul I understand the problem, I'm just not understanding your approach. How does "10:20:00.000Z" get calculated? Is it always 10:20:00? Do you use some method of calculating this? OR do you want every date to always be the same date but at 10:20?

Comment: @Isolated "10:20:00.000Z"  this part should vary with the variable

Comment: @mdkamrul so its always 10:20:000Z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Working with Date

Whilst I understand your logic of converting it to a string and then using string methods to convert it to your desired output, I believe a simpler approach is to use the `Date` object

```
function dateAdd(original, hours, minutes) {
  const date = new Date(original);

  date.setHours(original.getHours() + hours);
  date.setMinutes(original.getMinutes() + minutes);

  return date.toISOString();
}
```

When `original` = "2021-05-26T00:00:00.000Z" then the return value is "2021-05-26T10:20:00.000Z".

If you want a fixed time:

```
const date = new Date('2021-05-26T00:00:00.000Z');

date.setUTCHours(10);
date.setUTCMinutes(20);
date.setUTCSeconds(0);
date.setUTCMilliseconds(0);

// a cleaner approach:
date.setUTCHours(10, 20, 0); // hoursValue, minutesValue, secondsValue

console.log(date.toISOString());
```

Which produces the following:

```
"2021-05-26T10:20:00.000Z"
```

### Another Solution

Your actual problem is being caused by the fact you call `toString` which returns a date string in the format of "Tue Aug 19 1975 23:15:30 GMT+0200 (CEST)" so when you're splitting by "T", that's way down at the end. `toISOString` will return the correct format.

### Explanation

As you can see above, we avoid using string methods and use the methods that exist on `Date`. This approach is safer as you avoid issues with the difference between `toISOString` and `toString`. You may also find `moment` useful if you're using dynamic methods of changing dates regularly.

### Note

In all honesty, I'm not entirely sure I understand the *why* behind what you're doing, so if I'm wrong please correct me so I can update my answer to be more relevant for you.

### Learn More

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: for fixed time this giveing me "2021-05-26T05:20:00.000Z" not "2021-05-26T10:20:00.000Z"

Comment: @mdkamrul that's my fault. Should've been setUTCHours (I've updated this now).

Comment: this working fine thanks for your support